# Trying to understand and build a Core data model using relationships

Tags: swift, core-data

So i have done some research on Core data relationships with Swift, and i have a base understanding of the functionality, but i wanted to see if i could get some help on my specific model. What i want to do is get a user inputted question and answer and have that pair or pairs of questions and answers be saved to Core Data under a name. For the model, i was thinking i need to create a Questions entity with an attribute question, an Answers entity with an attribute answer and a Name entity with an attribute name. This is where i get confused on how i can make this work, or if it is even a correct model in order a deck name to be given, questions and answers be input and saved to that name only. Each time a new name is created, i want the new questions and answers to be saved to that name and so on. Thanks in advance for any help that can be given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Name -->> Question (one to many relationship)
Question --> Answer (one to one assuming there's just one answer per q)
```

Then you need to create reverse relationships for all of the above.

This is how it should look like in the editor:

[image: example of core data model]

Comment: All relationships should be bi-directional, which you do say but the example doesn't show.

Comment: Thank you, my friend. This is very helpful. Just one thing, by Name i meant a name for each specific group of questions and answers. For example, "Math" , "History, etc. Basically just a name to organize groups of questions and answers. So in that case would i swap out the User entity for a Name entity with an attribute of name?

Comment: Yes, create an entity called Name and use it instead of user in my diagram. Wain is right, in the picture I pasted questions ->> question does not have inverse relationship. In my experience it's better to always define one.

Comment: One small issue, i could not choose an inverse relationship under Name. I had to make another relationship under Question called questionName in order to choose an inverse relationship under name. Does this sound correct?